# How can I fix the 'nil value' error with Null-ls and Prettierd when running :lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting() in Neovim?

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

I am trying to setup prettier in neovim so I can format tsx files. I am using null-ls with prettier. But everytime I run `:lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting()` command, I am getting this error:
`E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: attempt to call field 'formatting' (a nil value) stack traceback: [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk`

Here is my null-ls config:

```
local status, null_ls = pcall(require, "null-ls")
if not status then
  return
end

null_ls.setup({
  sources = {
    null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.eslint.with({
      diagnostics_format = "[eslint] #{m} (#{c})"
    }),
    null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.fish,
    null_ls.builtins.formatting.prettierd.with({
      filetypes = {
        "css",
        "javascript",
        "javascriptreact",
        "typescript",
        "typescriptreact",
        "json",
        "scss",
        "less",
        "tsx"
      }
    }),
  },
  attach = function(client, bufnr)
    vim.api.nvim_command("autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting_sync(nil, 1000)")
  end,
  autostart = true, -- Set autostart to true
})
```

Also Here is my lsp config file

```
local status, nvim_lsp = pcall(require, "lspconfig")
if (not status) then return end

local protocol = require('vim.lsp.protocol')

local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  -- format on save
  if client.name == "tsserver" then
    client.resolved_capabilities.document_formatting = false
  end
  if client.resolved_capabilities.document_formatting then
    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePre", {
      group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("Format", { clear = true }),
      buffer = bufnr,
      callback = function()
        vim.lsp.buf.formatting_sync(nil, 1000)
      end
    })
  end
end

-- TypeScript
nvim_lsp.tsserver.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  filetypes = { "javascript", "javascriptreact", "typescript", "typescriptreact", "typescript.tsx", "jsx" },
  cmd = { "typescript-language-server", "--stdio" }
}
require'lspconfig'.lua_ls.setup {
  settings = {
    Lua = {
      runtime = {
        -- Tell the language server which version of Lua you're using (most likely LuaJIT in the case of Neovim)
        version = 'LuaJIT',
      },
      diagnostics = {
        -- Get the language server to recognize the `vim` global
        globals = { 'vim' },
      },
      workspace = {
        -- Make the server aware of Neovim runtime files
        library = vim.api.nvim_get_runtime_file("", true),
      },
      -- Do not send telemetry data containing a randomized but unique identifier
      telemetry = {
        enable = false,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Null-ls formatting problem--- `:lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting()` not working
I guess this issue is because I am using tsserver an dnull-ls side by side

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:lua vim.lsp.buf.format()`